# Implementing native android code with AIR code

Tags: java, android, air

After following [these instructions](http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/) to integrate Adobe AIR with native Android I have a few issues.

I have managed to get a bluetooth connection going in native android, setting up 2 BluetoothSockets which then shows the air app also packaged within the apk. This included air app requires 2 connections to somewhere (normally wifi).

I have it connecting to TestService1 and TestService2, which is then passing the traffic between these services and  the BluetoothSockets.

It is a little slow as i have to put Thread.sleep(80) in between reading from bt socket and writing to the AIR app for it to work currently.

My 2 questions are

Is there any way to get the AIR app to know about and access the Bluetooth Sockets created in the Android code rather than having the 2 Services being the middle men?

Is this kind of release (hybrid) allowed in Android Marketplace does anyone know?

Really hoping to find an answer to question 1 as currently my bluetooth server is continously sending data and using the TestService1 and 2 to get this bluetooth data to the AIR app and is causing a 10 seconds lag.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

These apps are definitely allowed in the Android market.

You should be able to send Bluetooth data immediately over the socket to the AIR app.  It doesn't seem like you should need 2 separate services or a sleep.  I think your service that is talking to the Bluetooth can also listen on a socket and send data over that socket when it gets it.

Comment: Hi James,Thank you so much for for getting back to me. I am at a losss of how to let the air app know about a socket(s) created in native android without having a service (with an address) to connect to first. I would be forever grateful if yourself or anyone else can point me in the direction of getting rid of the need to connect to these services to get data to and from bluetooth device and into the air app.

Comment: so its not possible to communicate between air and android really then? The lag created by writing to one socket which writes to another which sends a response back down the sockets is too much. There is no way whatsoever (i have been working on this a full 7 days) to get the natively created bluetooth socket (or any other native android object) to be accessed by the adobe air app. I have also asked this question numerous times during the week without an answer so im assuming its imposssible and therefore pointless to extend adobe air with android :{